# Assign values to ranges in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Noob question. I want to assign a value to defined slices of a Pandas DataFrame, but I can't figure out from the caveats text that the error message points to how to actually do this correctly.

Error message:
     SettingWithCopyWarning: 
     A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

My failing code:

```
df.ix[0]["points"] = 1
df.ix[1:2]["points"] = 2
df.ix[3:8]["points"] = 3
```

What is a proper way of doing this?

**UPDATE:**

As @Delforge comments below, the following works:

```
df.loc[0, ("points")] = 1
df.loc[1:2, ("points")] = 2
```

Comment: Could you provide sample input and output tables?

Comment: try using `pd.DataFrame.loc`. Example :  `df.loc[1:2, ("points")] = 2`

Comment: Note that .loc is strict when you present slicers that are not compatible (or convertible) with the index type. For example using integers in a DatetimeIndex. These will raise a TypeError. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Comment: @Delforge's answer did the trick! I didn't find that syntax out correctly from the docs.

Comment: @Delforge should be promoted to an answer

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you need .ix

Try

```
df["points"][0] = 1
df["points"][1:2] = 2
```

etc.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Comment: Also, see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy for information about why you got your error.

Comment: It would be helpful to see an example of your dataframe.

Comment: Also, when I try my code on a dataframe with a "points" column, it works, so it may be an issue of which version of Pandas you're using (I'm using 0.17.0). Glad to see you found a solution, though!